# 403 Forbidden nginx redirect using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I m trying to redirect 403 forbidden url to homepage but not able to redirect.

Here is what i have tried in .htaccess

`Redirect /ru-1/.html https:://test.com`

But it't not working i did same for othere URL and it was worked.

I think the problem is `/.html` part it is without prefix page name.

can anyone please guide me on this.

Comment: try this `Redirect /ru-1\.html https:://test.com`

Comment: Not working this

Comment: An nginx http server won't interpret ``.htaccess`` style dynamic configuration files.